# Can I have 45 degree view in osmdoird maps in android?

Tags: osmdroid

I wonder if there any perspective view in osmdroid? I mean 45 degree view so I be able to view map almost horizontally?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing similar to the [Google Maps Camera "tilt viewing angle"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#tilt_viewing_angle) in osmdroid.

That would be a nice feature...

Answer (score 0):

I find some interesting project of University of Bremen few days ago. I think it's can help you.
It's vector tiles map which use osmdroid as library and can change degree of view, you can get more info or example by this link - https://github.com/opensciencemap/vtm
I don't use it now, but want to use this in future.

WebGL Demo for example
http://opensciencemap.org/s3db/#scale=17&rot=40&tilt=65&lat=56.826&lon=60.615